# Migration from Wordpress AJAX error

Tags: ajax, migrations

I am currently working on WordPress content migration (all posts) to Drupal 7. I have downloaded the WordPress WXR file and checked with xmllint for validation. The file is valid and no issues found.

I have installed all required modules in Drupal (Migrate,
Wordpress Migrate, Migrate Extras, Pathauto) and started importing the XML file. After importing few fields of data, Drupal gives me an AJAX error.

> An error occurred. Some or all of the import processing has failed.
>   Please continue to the error page
>   An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally. Debugging information follows. Path: /newblog/batch?render=overlay&id=28&op=do StatusText: ResponseText: ReadyState: 4

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: AJAX ReadyState 4: request finished and response is ready. Are you getting this err in firebug?

Comment: try jquery update

Comment: Look at your error logs (admin/reports/dblog, the PHP error log), see if there's anything there.

Comment: Hi Bojan, I got this error. Warning: Missing argument 5 for migrate_ui_batch() in migrate_ui_batch() (line 309 of C:\wamp\www\newblog\sites\all\modules\migrate\migrate_ui\migrate_ui.pages.inc).

Comment: As per the last comment of the OP, I am closing this question. If the error is "missing argument 5 for `migrate_ui_batch()`," then it is a problem with the module. Report an error in the project queue, if there isn't a report already.